# Cordova app, file:// origin and CORS

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, cors

I'm currently working on a Cordova app written with AngularJS.
When I run the built APK on the android tablet or the iPad, the requests are sent with the "Origin" header set to "file://". This makes the server to reject the request for CORS reasons.

I've seen that the origin should be set to "null", not "file://" when Cordova sends the requests.

I'm actually using cordova-plugin-whitelist.
The communication between the app and the server is using SOAP protocol, and i'm using an external module in the frontend that sends the requests with XmlHttpRequest.

I don't wan't, for security reasons, to allow "file://" origin on server side. Is there any way to remove the origin from the requests ? I tried to manually set the Origin header of the XmlHttpRequest, but of course, it creates an error "Refused to set unsafe header "Origin"".

How could I make this work without impacting the security ? 
Does something like a Cordova plugin that removes the "Origin" header from all the AJAX exists ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an console error or some kind of error log we can see?

Comment: Hi @LBalsdon,
The only error log that I get is "POST [url] 403 (Forbidden)". 
When i go to the Network tab and inspect the request, the status is 403 and the response is :
"Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Filter: CORS origin denied: file://"

Comment: The CORS issue comes when your device is connected and inspecting in debugging mode in the browser. Because it is your browser issue. Try to run the app without connecting to the browser and give proper error validation in the $http POST and alert it.

Comment: As said, the applications uses an external module (angular-soap) to communicate with the server.
This module uses XmlHttpRequest.
I added an alert of the xhr response in the module, built a new APK, installed it on the tablet and unplugged the tablet from the computer.
Then I launched the app, tried to login, and the following alert is displayed :
"Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Filter: CORS origin denied: file://".
Did I respect the scenario you suggested ?

Comment: did you found a solution for that?

Comment: @BabarConnect did you found a solution for that? thx